# Scroll bar in one line code block the code

Tags: bug, safari, osx, horizontal-scroll-bar

Something is so annoying when a code snippet contains only one line of code, the scroll bar hides the code.

It would be good if the scroll bar have a specific area for it in the snippet box. See the screenshot:

[image]

**Note**: I'm using Safari v10.1 on macOS Sierra v10.12.4

Comment: This is because you have scroll bars set to only show when you scroll right? This is an OS thing and just how scrollbars work everywhere

Comment: Yeah but it's possible to workaround that by exceeding the height of the snippet box

Comment: Other browsers/OSes are sensible enough to do this themselves. (Pale Moon on Win 10, for example, adds the necessary vertical space when the scrollbar becomes necessary.)

Comment: Fwiw Chrome on Windows 7 also [correctly adds space for the scrollbar](https://i.snag.gy/HjhKG4.jpg).